# how to handling session time out in asp.net 3.5

Tags: web-config, asp.net-3.5

i 'm working with asp.net 3.5 and i'm just upset with session handling of asp.net. here it's automatically log out from session period.

here is my web config session time out:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
```

i just want to increase this time out for max as.

Is that possible for increase timeout="..." or buy default it's managed from iis machine.

Answer (score 0):

Its better that you mention the time out in web.config file and it take timeout in minute not in sec.

Comment: can i 'm setting to 60.